# Usar cast para un filtro en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 select  (select NOMCLI from CARROS where cast(IDCLI as int) = idreg1) as NOMCLI, fecha 
  from replog 
    where movimiento = 'ALT' and TABLA = 'CARROS' and usuario = 'sa'
```

Tengo un ejemplo acá donde el `idcli` es entero:327 y idreg1 es decimal: 327,00.

Hago esa consulta pero el `nomcli` me los trae todos nulos ¿como aplicaría el `cast` para hacer el filtro? o si hay otra manera.

Comment: pero si obtienes todo nulo, como quieres hacer cast?

Comment: No estan nulos creo que el problema es que la comparicion el filtro no se esta dando

Comment: cual es el resultado que obtienes?

Comment: NOMCLI en NULL y FECHAS bien

Comment: puedes revisar la respuesta de `Lamak` deberias hacerlo con `join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que todo, la comparación debería funcionar como está (aunque no entiendo por qué estás convirtiendo `IDCLI` a entero, si ya era ese tipo de dato).

De todas formas, la mejor manera de hacer esto es con un `JOIN`, no una subquery:

```
SELECT  c.NomCli,
        r.fecha
FROM replog r
LEFT JOIN carros c
    ON IdCli = CAST(idreg1 AS INT)
WHERE movimiento = 'ALT' 
AND TABLA = 'CARROS' 
AND usuario = 'sa';
```